# Recebendo json de um servidor da Web

Tags: c#, json, firebase, webrequest

Estou trabalhando com o firebase, e estou buscando os dados do servidor com HttpWebRequest, consegui recuperar esses dados da seguinte maneira;

> {"-L1OD7LjENM8ZHSpS7NE":{"Idade":"18
>   anos","Nome":"vitor","Telefone":"11
>   970705570"},"-L1ODHPKmz_1zcCfpZwF":{"Idade":"10 anos","Nome":"joao
>   ","Telefone":"9898294792"},"-L1ODMFC92yisdG4UxPU":{"Idade":"30
>   anos","Nome":"bruno","Telefone":"9898294792"}}

Usando esse código abaixo;

```
HttpWebRequest pesquisar = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(URL);
pesquisar.ContentType = "application/json: charset=utf-8";
HttpWebResponse pesquisar1 = pesquisar.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
using (Stream pesquisarStream = pesquisar1.GetResponseStream())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pesquisarStream, Encoding.UTF8);

            var text = reader.ReadToEnd();

            richTextBox1.Text = text;
}
```

Eu gostaria de receber esses dados, direto em um arquivo json e criar uma lista pra poder manipular tanto os dados, quanto as keys.

Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Por favor, explique um pouco mais... a __var text__ já não tem o conteúdo do json como string, algo como __{ obj : valor }__ ?

Comment: Hey man, esse JSon ta estranho, o que significa isso ? L1OD7LjENM8ZHSpS7NE

Comment: L1OD7LjENM8ZHSpS7NE  isso é a key do arquivo json que é gerada pelo firebase

Comment: gustavo eu tenho os dados como string, preciso transformar eles em uma lista, nessa string tem dados de 3 usuários, preciso separar os dados e as keys em lista pra poder trabalhar com eles

Answer (score 0):

Se me permite, gostaria de te indicar uma boa forma de resolver esse problema:
Instale o pacote do NewtonSoft pelo Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/10.0.3

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Então, transforme a string recebida em uma lista dinâmica para poder trabalhar:

```
var listaDinamica = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(text);
```

Depois disso, obtenha os valores dos elementos, de forma a remover os indices:

```
var lista = listaDinamica.Select(x => ((JProperty)x).Value.ToObject<Cliente>()).ToList();
```

Nesse ponto, caso necessite do Index, vc pode usar o (JProperty)x).Path no lugar do (JProperty)x).Value. Poderia ainda criar um dicionário para retornar chave e valor (cuidado com indice duplicado).

Após esse ponto, adicionei um simples WriteLine para apresentar no console, mas ai você já vai ter a lista de objeto que deseja.
Veja abaixo o código todo:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Cliente
        {
            public string Idade { get; set; }
            public string Telefone { get; set; }
            public string Nome { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var text = "{\"-L1OD7LjENM8ZHSpS7NE\":{\"Idade\":\"18 anos\",\"Nome\":\"vitor\",\"Telefone\":\"11 970705570\"},\"-L1ODHPKmz_1zcCfpZwF\":{\"Idade\":\"10 anos\",\"Nome\":\"joao \",\"Telefone\":\"9898294792\"},\"-L1ODMFC92yisdG4UxPU\":{\"Idade\":\"30 anos\",\"Nome\":\"bruno\",\"Telefone\":\"9898294792\"}}";

            var listaDinamica = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(text);
            var lista = listaDinamica.Select(x => ((JProperty)x).Value.ToObject<Cliente>()).ToList();

            foreach (var item in lista)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Nome);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: A imagem do resultado]

Veja funcionando em: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LjGMeG

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas estou tendo alguns problemas aqui nao esta reconhecendo o JToken, nem esse listaDinamica.Select, nao sei como prosseguir